# How to extract month from date time picker in a string format

Tags: vb.net

I want month in a string format from date time picker in vb. Net. Please help me

Comment: 1) VB.NET and VB6 are not the same thing. 2) What have you tried? A simple google search would return at least hundreds of results answering this question.

Comment: You need to find out how to use `.ToString()` on a DateTime. Then find out how to get a DateTime from a DateTimePicker. Put the two together and you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer will depend on your local date format. In the following code, in the UK, `longDate` will be assigned "06 May 2018". The next line splits `longDate` into an array of 3 elements using the space character as the split point :-

element 0 = "06"

element 1 = "May"

element 2 = "2018"

and returns element 1 to `monthString`

```
    Dim longDate As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString
    Dim monthString As String = longDate.Split(" "c)(1)
```

If your month is the first element, then you will need to change `(1)` to `(0)`